# Waiting for SSH to be available with docker-machine on windows 10

Tags: ssh, docker-machine

I [installed](https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/) docker machine, and then [created a new docker-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62726122/1977871) on Windows 10.

Now I run ls to see the list of docker machines.

[image: docker-machine ls command]

Now I run the following command

```
docker-machine start hypervdockermachine
```

Now I am stuck at this

Waiting for SSH to be available...
Too many retries waiting for SSH to be available.  Last error: Maximum number of retries (60) exceeded

[image: Waiting for SSH to be available problem]

I have seen the [git hub issue here](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/4053), but not clear what to do.

Is there a way to solve this problem? I am not good at ssh

**UPDATE**

I just found a workaround.

You can run the above commands with [git bash](https://git-scm.com/downloads).

[image: with git bash]

Most important, you must **run git bash as admin**. Else you will end up scratching your head.

Even the basic

```
docker-machine ls
```

will not show up anything without being an admin.

Finally if you are seeing the following error

```
Unable to query docker version: Get https://192.168.0.105:2376/v1.15/version: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Then you have to look at [this issue](https://github.com/sparkfabrik/sparkdock/issues/14).

```
docker-machine regenerate-certs yourdockermachinename
```

If needed user --force option

Answer (score 0):

I got into the same problem after I moved `.docker` to partition `D:` and created a symlink to `C:\Users\username\.docker`, following this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45492583/1854332). I removed the old machines and configured new ones, and tried to regenerate the certs as suggested in the OP workaround but the problem was not solved.

After googling, I found [this](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Security-protection-of-various-files-in-Win32-OpenSSH) OpenSSH wiki page
and suspected that the cause of the problem was related to permissions.

So I could solve the problem by trying two different things:

1. Delete `.ssh` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51644368/1854332))
2. fix permissions to `D:\path\to\.docker`, allowing **only** SYSTEM, Administrators and my user to have full control access ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50624841/1854332)). These permissions were the same defined for `.docker` when it was under `C:\Users\username\`, but moving the folder to another partition made it inherit different permissions. To avoid dealing to much with it, I keep inheritance enabled changed the permissions directly in `D:` rather than in `.docker` folder.